# cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'xsi:schemalocation' is not allowed to appear in element 'jtis_journey_list'

Tags: java, xml, xsd

i have to parse an xml file with validation regarding XSD. but when i parse the xml file with JAXB i found some error in parsing
XSD file

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           targetNamespace="http://data.one.gov.hk/td" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="jtis_journey_list">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="jtis_journey_time" 
                    maxOccurs="unbounded" 
                    minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="location_id"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="destination_id"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="capture_date" 
                          minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="journey_type"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="journey_data"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="colour_id"/> 
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="journey_desc" 
                          minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:choice>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jtis_journey_list 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://data.one.gov.hk/td 
                      http://data.one.gov.hk/xsd/td/journeytime.xsd" 
  xmlns="http://data.one.gov.hk/td">
  <jtis_journey_time>
    <LOCATION_ID>H11</LOCATION_ID>
    <DESTINATION_ID>CH</DESTINATION_ID>
    <CAPTURE_DATE>2016-07-01T14:56:35</CAPTURE_DATE>
    <JOURNEY_TYPE>1</JOURNEY_TYPE>
    <JOURNEY_DATA>12</JOURNEY_DATA>
    <COLOUR_ID>3</COLOUR_ID>
    <JOURNEY_DESC></JOURNEY_DESC>
  </jtis_journey_time>
  <jtis_journey_time>
    <LOCATION_ID>H11</LOCATION_ID>
    <DESTINATION_ID>EH</DESTINATION_ID>
    <CAPTURE_DATE>2016-07-01T14:56:35</CAPTURE_DATE>
    <JOURNEY_TYPE>1</JOURNEY_TYPE>
    <JOURNEY_DATA>4</JOURNEY_DATA>
    <COLOUR_ID>3</COLOUR_ID>
    <JOURNEY_DESC></JOURNEY_DESC>
  </jtis_journey_time>
</jtis_journey_list>
```

While parsing the file I found an error:

> cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'xsi:schemalocation' is not allowed to appear in element 'jtis_journey_list'.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In your source document the attribute is correctly spelled

```
xsi:schemaLocation
```

But in the error message it has the spelling

```
xsi:schemalocation
          ^
```

I suspect that you are showing us the corrected version, and that the document you actually validated had the incorrect spelling.